# How to display remote html page in modal window in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap example:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-default"
     data-toggle="modal"
     data-target="#remoteModal"
     href="remote-page.html">Open modal window</a>
```

Could I do the same using Angular bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or using another library?

Comment: Does your url returns you html page when you hit it? I don't have any idea about angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to "embed" the remote page on your modal markup, an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) is one way to do it.

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <iframe src="https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/snippets/html/iframe-simple-contents.html" width="400" height="300">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

[Here's a forked plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/sjWit1uJkf1UpRRDE2qO?p=preview) from the modal examples.